# how to get Price of Cryptocurrency with web3js

Tags: solidity, web3js, smart-contract-wallets

is there any way to get PRICE of any crypto currency with web3JS or solidity. I wanna make something amazing : )

USDT and USDC are also not constant, is there any other way, other than comparing its value with constant tokens e.g. USDT.

Comment: Maybe using Uniswap v3?
https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/guides/fetching-prices

Answer (score 0):

According to [Ethereum's documentation](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/oracles/), you should use an Oracle for this task.

Since the blockchain is deterministic the data needs to be first added to the blockchain. That is the job of the Oracle smart contracts.  They receive data from an external source and save it via a transaction onto the blockchain.

I suggest looking into something like [Chain link Data Feeds](https://data.chain.link/) which already have hundreds of common pairings across 9 chains as of this writing.  They can be used within smart contracts or on the client side.

If you create your own tokens you can even use the [Uniswap V3 liquidity pools as oracles](https://docs.uniswap.org/protocol/concepts/V3-overview/oracle).

Answer (score 0):

If it's on an Dex, get pair address with the router contract and then call getReserves(). It will be the rate between Weth (Wrapped Ether) and the token on the pool.

For USD price grab the price of an stablecoin and then multyply by the rate between the token and the Weth.

Comment: Note: This only works for DEXs that are uniswap v2 or a fork of it. It won't work for Uniswap v3

Answer (score 0):

We use Oracle like chianlink to get data from offchain.

Include [below code](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x7a73035b1404c6a73e99d49786ded46592412fb9#code) in your project.

After Deploying the code,

In PriceFeed.sol, do call [setAddress](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x39b6e2cd25618adff9050b8910a5db5e3f001247bbec9de39dd93fb3b5134dc4) function, and give `_priceAggregatorAddress` parameter as required oracle address for respective chain, network and currency pair from [here](https://docs.chain.link/docs/reference-contracts/)

i.e. for rinkeby ETH/USD price I entred [0x8A753747A1Fa494EC906cE90E9f37563A8AF630e](https://docs.chain.link/docs/ethereum-addresses/).

To get price, you need to call [fetchPrice()](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x7a73035b1404c6a73e99d49786ded46592412fb9#readContract) function.

*Note: Handle decimals, divide price by required decimals.*

Here is complete [code](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x7a73035b1404c6a73e99d49786ded46592412fb9#code) that you will require.

Here is one transaction of [setAddress()](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x39b6e2cd25618adff9050b8910a5db5e3f001247bbec9de39dd93fb3b5134dc4)

Below is same code from rinkeby scan which you can refer

**PriceFeed.sol**

```
// PriceFeed.sol file
// SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT

pragma solidity >=0.8.0;


import "./Ownable.sol";

import "./IPriceFeed.sol";
import "./AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

/*
* PriceFeed for mainnet deployment, to be connected to Chainlink's live ETH:USD aggregator reference 
* contract, and a wrapper contract TellorCaller, which connects to TellorMaster contract.
*
* The PriceFeed uses Chainlink as primary oracle, and Tellor as fallback. It contains logic for
* switching oracles based on oracle failures, timeouts, and conditions for returning to the primary
* Chainlink oracle.
*/
contract PriceFeed is Ownable, IPriceFeed {

    string constant public NAME = "PriceFeed";

    AggregatorV3Interface public priceAggregator;  // Mainnet Chainlink aggregator

    uint constant public DECIMAL_PRECISION = 1e18;

    // Use to convert a price answer to an 18-digit precision uint
    uint constant public TARGET_DIGITS = 18;  

    // Maximum time period allowed since Chainlink's latest round data timestamp, beyond which Chainlink is considered frozen.
    uint constant public TIMEOUT = 14400;  // 4 hours: 60 * 60 * 4
    
    // Maximum deviation allowed between two consecutive Chainlink oracle prices. 18-digit precision.
    uint constant public MAX_PRICE_DEVIATION_FROM_PREVIOUS_ROUND =  5e17; // 50%

    /* 
    * The maximum relative price difference between two oracle responses allowed in order for the PriceFeed
    * to return to using the Chainlink oracle. 18-digit precision.
    */
    uint constant public MAX_PRICE_DIFFERENCE_BETWEEN_ORACLES = 5e16; // 5%

    // The last good price seen from an oracle by ourProject
    uint public lastGoodPrice;

    struct ChainlinkResponse {
        uint80 roundId;
        int256 answer;
        uint256 timestamp;
        bool success;
        uint8 decimals;
    }

    enum Status {
        chainlinkWorking, 
        usingTellorChainlinkUntrusted, 
        bothOraclesUntrusted,
        usingTellorChainlinkFrozen, 
        usingChainlinkTellorUntrusted
    }

    // The current status of the PricFeed, which determines the conditions for the next price fetch attempt
    Status public status;

    // --- Dependency setters ---
    
    function setAddress(
        address _priceAggregatorAddress
    )
        external
        onlyOwner
    {
       
        priceAggregator = AggregatorV3Interface(_priceAggregatorAddress);

        emit PriceAggregatorAddressChanged(_priceAggregatorAddress);

        // Explicitly set initial system status
        status = Status.chainlinkWorking;

        // Get an initial price from Chainlink to serve as first reference for lastGoodPrice
        ChainlinkResponse memory chainlinkResponse = _getCurrentChainlinkResponse();

        _storeChainlinkPrice(chainlinkResponse);
    }

    // --- Functions ---

    /*
    * fetchPrice():
    * Returns the latest price obtained from the Oracle. Called by ourProject functions that require a current price.
    *
    * Also callable by anyone externally.
    *
    * Non-view function - it stores the last good price seen by ourProject.
    *
    * Uses a main oracle (Chainlink) and a fallback oracle (Tellor) in case Chainlink fails. If both fail, 
    * it uses the last good price seen by ourProject.
    *
    */
    function fetchPrice() external view override returns (uint) {
        // Get current and previous price data from Chainlink, and current price data from Tellor
        ChainlinkResponse memory _chainlinkResponse = _getCurrentChainlinkResponse();
        uint scaledChainlinkPrice = _scaleChainlinkPriceByDigits(uint256(_chainlinkResponse.answer), _chainlinkResponse.decimals);
        return scaledChainlinkPrice;
    }

    function _storePrice(uint _currentPrice) internal {
        lastGoodPrice = _currentPrice;
        emit LastGoodPriceUpdated(_currentPrice);
    }

    function _scaleChainlinkPriceByDigits(uint _price, uint _answerDigits) internal pure returns (uint) {
        /*
        * Convert the price returned by the Chainlink oracle to an 18-digit decimal for use by ourProject.
        * At date of ourProject launch, Chainlink uses an 8-digit price, but we also handle the possibility of
        * future changes.
        *
        */
        uint price;
        if (_answerDigits >= TARGET_DIGITS) {
            // Scale the returned price value down to ourProject's target precision
            price = _price / (10 ** (_answerDigits - TARGET_DIGITS));
        }
        else if (_answerDigits < TARGET_DIGITS) {
            // Scale the returned price value up to ourProject's target precision
            price = _price * (10 ** (TARGET_DIGITS - _answerDigits));
        }
        return price;
    }
    
    function _storeChainlinkPrice(ChainlinkResponse memory _chainlinkResponse) internal returns (uint) {
        uint scaledChainlinkPrice = _scaleChainlinkPriceByDigits(uint256(_chainlinkResponse.answer), _chainlinkResponse.decimals);
        _storePrice(scaledChainlinkPrice);

        return scaledChainlinkPrice;
    }

    function _getCurrentChainlinkResponse() internal view returns (ChainlinkResponse memory chainlinkResponse) {
        // First, try to get current decimal precision:
        try priceAggregator.decimals() returns (uint8 decimals) {
            // If call to Chainlink succeeds, record the current decimal precision
            chainlinkResponse.decimals = decimals;
        } catch {
            // If call to Chainlink aggregator reverts, return a zero response with success = false
            return chainlinkResponse;
        }

        // Secondly, try to get latest price data:
        try priceAggregator.latestRoundData() returns
        (
            uint80 roundId,
            int256 answer,
            uint256 /* startedAt */,
            uint256 timestamp,
            uint80 /* answeredInRound */
        )
        {
            // If call to Chainlink succeeds, return the response and success = true
            chainlinkResponse.roundId = roundId;
            chainlinkResponse.answer = answer;
            chainlinkResponse.timestamp = timestamp;
            chainlinkResponse.success = true;
            return chainlinkResponse;
        } catch {
            // If call to Chainlink aggregator reverts, return a zero response with success = false
            return chainlinkResponse;
        }
    }

}
```

**AggregatorV3Interface.sol**

```
// AggregatorV3Interface.sol file
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// Code from https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/master/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol

pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

interface AggregatorV3Interface {

  function decimals() external view returns (uint8);
  function description() external view returns (string memory);
  function version() external view returns (uint256);

  // getRoundData and latestRoundData should both raise "No data present"
  // if they do not have data to report, instead of returning unset values
  // which could be misinterpreted as actual reported values.
  function getRoundData(uint80 _roundId)
    external
    view
    returns (
      uint80 roundId,
      int256 answer,
      uint256 startedAt,
      uint256 updatedAt,
      uint80 answeredInRound
    );

  function latestRoundData()
    external
    view
    returns (
      uint80 roundId,
      int256 answer,
      uint256 startedAt,
      uint256 updatedAt,
      uint80 answeredInRound
    );
}
```

**Context.sol**

```
//Context.sol file
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// OpenZeppelin Contracts v4.4.1 (utils/Context.sol)

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

/**
 * @dev Provides information about the current execution context, including the
 * sender of the transaction and its data. While these are generally available
 * via msg.sender and msg.data, they should not be accessed in such a direct
 * manner, since when dealing with meta-transactions the account sending and
 * paying for execution may not be the actual sender (as far as an application
 * is concerned).
 *
 * This contract is only required for intermediate, library-like contracts.
 */
abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes calldata) {
        return msg.data;
    }
}
```

**IPriceFeed.sol**

```
//IPriceFeed.sol file
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity >=0.8.0;

interface IPriceFeed {
    // -- Events ---
    event LastGoodPriceUpdated(uint _lastGoodPrice);
    event PriceAggregatorAddressChanged(address _priceAggregatorAddress);

    // ---Function---
    function fetchPrice() external view returns (uint);
}
```

**Ownable.sol**

```
//Ownable.sol file
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
// OpenZeppelin Contracts (last updated v4.7.0) (access/Ownable.sol)

pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "./Context.sol";

/**
 * @dev Contract module which provides a basic access control mechanism, where
 * there is an account (an owner) that can be granted exclusive access to
 * specific functions.
 *
 * By default, the owner account will be the one that deploys the contract. This
 * can later be changed with {transferOwnership}.
 *
 * This module is used through inheritance. It will make available the modifier
 * `onlyOwner`, which can be applied to your functions to restrict their use to
 * the owner.
 */
abstract contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;

    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);

    /**
     * @dev Initializes the contract setting the deployer as the initial owner.
     */
    constructor() {
        _transferOwnership(_msgSender());
    }

    /**
     * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner.
     */
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        _checkOwner();
        _;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Returns the address of the current owner.
     */
    function owner() public view virtual returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    /**
     * @dev Throws if the sender is not the owner.
     */
    function _checkOwner() internal view virtual {
        require(owner() == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
    }

    /**
     * @dev Leaves the contract without owner. It will not be possible to call
     * `onlyOwner` functions anymore. Can only be called by the current owner.
     *
     * NOTE: Renouncing ownership will leave the contract without an owner,
     * thereby removing any functionality that is only available to the owner.
     */
    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        _transferOwnership(address(0));
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfers ownership of the contract to a new account (`newOwner`).
     * Can only be called by the current owner.
     */
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        _transferOwnership(newOwner);
    }

    /**
     * @dev Transfers ownership of the contract to a new account (`newOwner`).
     * Internal function without access restriction.
     */
    function _transferOwnership(address newOwner) internal virtual {
        address oldOwner = _owner;
        _owner = newOwner;
        emit OwnershipTransferred(oldOwner, newOwner);
    }
}
```

Note: If warning for license arises, remove 1st line of every contract

Credits: Answer inspired form [Liquity](https://github.com/liquity/dev/blob/main/packages/contracts/contracts/PriceFeed.sol) and [Patrick Collins](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M576WGiDBdQ&ab_channel=freeCodeCamp.org)